# Should databases be viewed as Monads?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell, scala, monad

Because any kind of persistence updates/inserts/deletes represents in some sense a kind of state change in a database, it makes me wonder whether databases can be considered monads. We say the same about monads in functional programming.

What one can possibly gain or lose while designing a system with such thought process?

Comment: ["let's start talking about a monad..."](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/206543/31260)

Comment: If you are using Haskell you basically *have* to think of the database as a monad. See for example HaskellDB http://chrisdone.com/posts/haskelldb-tutorial which uses a `Query`-monad as the interface.

Comment: @JacquesB: HaskellDB is a database interface library, not a database.

Comment: There are powerful ways of applying monads to databases, for an older example see [Kleisli](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~wongls/psZ/wls-jfp98-3.pdf), but what you describe is not it. There are also [more modern categorical perspectives on databases](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/informatics/pure/) which is not focused on monads but does also use them at times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really.

A database is a facility for the structured and organized storage and retrieval of data.  A monad is a way to communicate with that database in a manner that preserves functional purity.

Think of the monad as a converter from the pure, immutable, mathematical world of the functional programming language; to the impure, mutable world of I/O.  Because your mutable side effects are sequestered behind the monad, you can "pretend" that you're still living in a perfect, immutable world on the other side of the monad.

But, at the end of the day, it's still just a monad.  There can be anything on the mutable side of that monad: a database, a console, another computer running Eliza.

Comment: Monads have far broader uses than that. While I agree that the specific(!) monad the OP talks about is not super useful, sets *do* form monads. If you make a universal relation, then your entire database is represented by one set of tuples; it is a monadic value. While it's more useful to look at individual tables as sets and thus monadic values, this is *not* a triviality. `do` notation or monad comprehensions become a query language and monad laws become query optimization rules.

Answer (score 3):

Databases are frequently modeled as monads in functional programming.  [HaskellDb](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskelldb-2.2.4/docs/Database-HaskellDB.html), [Quill](http://getquill.io/), [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/), and [Doobie](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie) are some examples I'm aware of. You can argue there's a difference between the database itself and the programming interface to the database.  I'm not sure that's a useful distinction in this context.

More precisely, an *operation* on a database *table* is frequently modeled as a monad.  So the `return` function wraps some table representation (like a record or class) into an internal query form that can be used for further transformations (taking a `record` to a `Query record` for example).  The `bind` function (called `>>=` in Haskell) transforms the wrapped query action using the given function.  For example, adding a `WHERE` clause to the query.

Since most collection types are also monads, this enables treating database tables like regular collections.  You can use the same simplifications you use for other monads:  Control.Monad library, do notation, for comprehensions, composition, etc.  The structure of your query is type checked.  If you add macros to the mix, like Quill does, the SQL can be generated at compile time.  It's quite a useful abstraction.

Comment: `Since most collection types are also monads, this enables treating database tables like regular collections.` Databases are an example of a collection type which *isn't* really a monad. (What database would `return a` be, for example?)

Comment: I already addressed this in my answer.  When `a` is a record, `return a` represents a database table.  Granted, this is a restriction on the type of `a`, but it is still a monad.  Other monads, like sets, have restrictions on the underlying type.  This isn't some theory I'm spouting.  People have implemented this and use it in real life production code.

Comment: well, I would specify what category you're working in, since otherwise your answer is ambiguous. (Also, the set monad, for example, is quite difficult to work with in Haskell.)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a Monad represents some sort of way of doing computations. For example, `Maybe` is a monad that enables computations to fail. `[]` is a computation that allows multiple results. `IO` is a monad that allows communication with the nebulous `RealWorld`.

A database isn't really that. You could have `State DataBase`, which would be a computation with one mutable variable (namely, a `DataBase`), but the DataBase itself probably can't been seen as monad.

Lookup `return` and `>>=`. Every monad needs to have these. Do databases have them?